# 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So, I'm having this error with AS3. I have an object(movie clip) called Inimigo2_Caique2, and his is called Inimigo2_Caique2, too. (I don't know why, but the icon of the object in the library is green instead of blue).

When I try to run the file, I get this error message:

5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Inimigo2_Caique2, removeListeners

I have other object called Inimigo_Caique2, and another class called Inimigo_Caique2. (The icon is green too.)

Here is the code of my Inimigo2_Caique2 class:

```
    package{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Inimigo2_Caique2 extends Sprite{
        private var palco:Object;
        private var yd:Number;
        private var xd:Number;
        public function Inimigo2_Caique2(){
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,inicia2);
        }
        private function inicia2(e:Event){
            palco=MovieClip(root);
            yd=palco.aviao.y-y;
            xd=palco.aviao.x-x;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop1);
        }
        private function loop1(e:Event){
            var angulo:Number=Math.atan2(yd,xd);
            x+=Math.cos(angulo)*10;
            y+=Math.sin(angulo)*10;
            for(var i:int = 0; i<palco.recipiente.numChildren;i++){
                var alvoBala2:Sprite = palco.recipiente.getChildAt(i);
                var ris:Number=alvoBala2.y-y;
                var run:Number=alvoBala2.x-x;
                var dis:Number=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ris,2)+Math.pow(run,2));
                if(dis<100){
                    if(run<0){
                        x+=20;
                    }else{
                        x-=20;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(hitTestObject(alvoBala2)){
                palco.recipiente.getChildAt(i).removeListeners();
                palco.recipiente.removeChild(alvoBala2);
                palco.Som2.play();
                var boom3:MovieClip = new explosao();
                boom3.x=x;
                boom3.y=y;
                stage.addChild(boom3);
                palco.pontos+=300;
                var textopontos=String(palco.pontos);
                palco.txt_pontos.text=textopontos;
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop1);
                palco.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
        if(hitTestObject(palco.aviao)){
            palco.Som2.play();
            var aviaoboom:MovieClip = new explosao();
            aviaoboom.x=palco.aviao.x;
            aviaoboom.y=palco.aviao.y;
            stage.addChild(aviaoboom);
            palco.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
    public function removeListeners():void{
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop1);
    }
}
```

I don't know why this is happening. I've already checked the brackets and everything, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance. This error is driving me mad.

Comment: It's quite simple: you just have to move to the end of your code, the curly brace which is just above " if (hitTestObject (palco.aviao)) { "

Answer (score 2):

In the following case, the function `myFunction` is *outside* of the public class `Main` and interpreted as another class by the compiler:

**My class**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

    }
    //
    public function myFunction()
        {

        }
    //
}
```

**My Fla**

```
myFunction(); // function invoked
```

This error message occurs: *5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Main, myFunction*, because the correct code is:

**My class**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function myFunction()
        {
            trace('myFunction should be here');
        }
    }
}
```

So your error message indicates that your function `removeListeners` is outside of your class `Inimigo2_Caique2`

**Remark**

As MasterRoro says, this block seems to be outside your loop1 function:

```
if (hitTestObject(palco.aviao)) {
    palco.Som2.play();
    var aviaoboom:MovieClip = new explosao();
    aviaoboom.x=palco.aviao.x;
    aviaoboom.y=palco.aviao.y;
    stage.addChild(aviaoboom);
    palco.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your block:

```
    if(hitTestObject(palco.aviao)){
        palco.Som2.play();
        var aviaoboom:MovieClip = new explosao();
        aviaoboom.x=palco.aviao.x;
        aviaoboom.y=palco.aviao.y;
        stage.addChild(aviaoboom);
        palco.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
} //Extra curly brace
```

Is supposed to go inside of your `loop1(e:Event)` function. You terminated the `loop1` function earlier than this with 2 curly braces, and then the extra curly brace in said block is terminating your class definition, which is why the compiler is throwing that error.

Try moving this block inside of the loop1() function and removing the extra curly brace at the end.